# How do I create a Polymer Dart component that inherits parent document CSS?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, web-component

Let's say I have a polymer component that's purpose is just to wrap up some boilerplate HTML;

```
<link rel="import" href="/packages/polymer/polymer.html"> 

<polymer-element name="form-group" noscript>
  <template>
    <div class="row form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-3">Blah</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <content></content>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

This renders the HTML as expected, but the CSS classes don't work, because the Shadow DOM is isolated fro the main projects CSS. I believe it might be possible to re-import the CSS here; but from what I've read, it seems like Shadow DOM is a bit overkill for this, so I'd like to avoid it.

I found [Allow creating polymer-elements without Shadow DOM](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/222) on GitHub, but it's been closed, and resolution seems to only apply to the polyfills.

I also found something suggested I could just remove the `<template>` tags, but that doesn't work either (nothing gets rendered in the page at all, and there are no errors!).

I'm aware of `applyAuthorStyles`, but it was removed, and I can't really find any info on why, or what is intended to be the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible solutions:

1. use selectors that pierce through ShadowDOM

```
* /deep/ .row.form-group
```

2. create an external CSS file and link it to each template where you want to have it applied

There was a way to create elements in the light DOM but it was limited and I didn't see it mentioned for a long time (I also have never used it myself).

More details can be found here:

- https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html
- https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html

Comment: (1) isn't possible; the CSS is not mine, I just want it to flow through, (2) I mentioned this in the question (though had written 'implement' instead of 'import'!), seems to ignore that tons of Shadow DOMs for tiny HTML tags is probably an unwanted overhead :(

Comment: I see (still) two reasonable solutions. 1) drop the CSS you have or 2) drop Polymer. You won't enjoy working with CSS frameworks (like Bootstrap) that don't support ShadowDOM in combination with bootstrap.

Comment: Oh man. So these new fangled web-components can't save us from a bit of boilerplate HTML? :O( I feel [another blog post](http://blog.dantup.com/2014/05/web-development-sucks-and-its-not-getting-any-better/) coming on... ;O(

Comment: I'm gonna drop Polymer (and Web Components). I already had doubts about it; and after re-reading about how the polyfills work (for non-Shadow DOM browsers), it's starting to look way too fragile :(

Comment: You try to use something with Web Components that's not built for it. I guess the biggest disadvantage of Web Components is that you can't use existing CSS frameworks. This is disruptive but these CSS frameworks are built with the tools of the past. Material design points to the future. It is not possible to polyfill everything especially when performance is important. I think they are working quite well but there are things that need some manual help. You can't expect a new technology in developer preview state to solve all your problems.

Comment: Web Components originally had support for this! This has nothing to do with being built with "tools for the past", it's just a design choice to not support something that I think is in serious need in web dev. It's nothing to do with polyfills; my question has no requirement that whatever the solution is works in any particular browser(s) :(

Comment: Support for Web components without ShadowDOM was not a design choice. Because there were so many complaints about problems with Bootstrap they tried to add this later but no attempt was working well. They just dropped this experimental support at some point. I haven't heard complaints about this for months.
In your previous comment you mentioned that you saw that polyfills don't work well. My comment relates to that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how choosing not to do something is not a design choice! There's nothing to stop them doing this except technical complication; that's still a choice (though TBH, I'd find it hard to believe it's more complicated to implement without Shadow DOM than with!). This issue isn't isolated to Bootstrap; having only Shadow DOM suggests that WC are not intended for simply wrapping up boilerplate; which IMO is a mistake :(

Comment: Sorry, my comment about polyfills wasn't directly related to the question; it was just something else that makes WC look like a bad idea (and ironically, is an issue because of Shadow DOM, so if I could avoid Shadow DOM, the polyfills would work fine!) :(

Comment: There is some misunderstanding. For a while there was some support for ShadowDOM-less Web Components as you yourself mentioned. Adding this was not really a design choice, this was added because of community pressure. But was then later dropped because they decided it isn't worth the effort. It is definitely not intended for that. Maybe you should use just HTML Imports without Polymer and Custom Elements.

Comment: /deep/ is not well supported outside of Chrome, I've found.

Comment: That makes it a decision! ;) HTML Imports won't work, to do what I want would be more effort than just including the boilerplate HTML. Seems like a massive opportunity missed, IMO!

Comment: @JohnEvans For browsers without Shadow DOM support you need to duplicate the selectors, one with `/deep/` and one without (basically, there are situations that required different modifications. As far as I know this is done automatically for style sheets inside Polymer elements but if you add style sheets in the document header you have to take care of this manually.